# Reportando - medalhas ficaram com descrição em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

As descrições das medalhas como a `altruísta` e `benfeitor` estão em inglês, antes estas e outras descrições estavam em português, logo estou reportando este acontecimento para que os moderadores possam tomar alguma providencia (se for possível).

Comment: Quando encontrar alguma palavra/frase em inglês, [você mesmo pode traduzir](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2705/mil-tradutores-s%c3%a3o-melhores-que-um). Verifiquei aqui a [página do projeto](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/) e ambas as frases já foram traduzidas, acontece que é preciso passar pelas revisões do utluiz, bfavaretto e Gabe antes de serem substituídas no site. Acho que nesse caso basta aguardar.

Comment: @renan, não conhecia esse trabalho é necessário algum privilégio especial?

Comment: Não, todo mundo pode ajudar. Você só precisa ter uma conta no Transifex, acessar a página do projeto e clicar no botão "Entrar na equipe". Depois que um dos responsáveis pelo projeto aceitar sua solicitação já poderá traduzir.

Answer (score 2):

Só confirmando:

1. Essas strings já estão traduzidas e revisadas no Transifex

   - https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/40271716
   - https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/40271789
2. Falta a revisão final do Gabe para poderem ir para o ar.